# Creating an Order Log That Tracks attainment to quota

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 tables in Access. One table is where Manual Data entry occurs that inputs a Partner name and How much the deal was made for. The Second table I want to track the sum of all the deals each partner has made up to that point. This would be to track their quota attainment. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Edit. I misunderstood. You don't need a table for this. You can just do a query. But, I can still help you with the table. What are the fields for table 1?

Comment: Don't need second table, build an aggregate query or a report.

Comment: For Table 1 I have Partner Name, Close date, The amount the Partner gets paid, and what kind of deal it is (On Premise or Cloud). The reason I thought a second table would be better is because each partner has a different quota to reach. If this can still be done with a query please let me know! Thanks!